# Assign slice to another slice of same data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

Consider the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, None, 3, None]}, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I want to replace to the nan values with some other values from the same data frame, for example:

```
df.loc[[2, 4]] = df.loc[[0, 1]]
```

But that does not work. The result is the exact same data frame as before the assignment. What I can do, however, is

```
df.loc[[2, 4]] = 999
```

and

```
df.loc[[2, 4]] = [999, 777]
```

and consequently also

```
df.loc[[2, 4]] = df.loc[[0, 1]].to_numpy().tolist()
```

All these examples replace the indexed values with the values given on the rhs, as expected.

Question is, why does the first assignment not work in the same manner? If that's a noop, I think, there should at least be warning.

Comment: it fails because pandas aligns on index before assignment. you've got indices 2,4 which wont align with 0,1. However, in the other solutions that work, there were no indices to align, that's why they worked. You probably dont even need the tolist(), the conversion to numpy is sufficient

Comment: Ah, sure! So, if the indexes of the slices match, the assignment works, e.g., `d.loc[[2, 4]] = d.loc[[0, 1]].set_index(d.loc[[2, 4]].index)`.

Comment: You can also try to convert the results into list, which removes the indexes and then assign the values back like this `df.loc[[2, 4], 'a'] = df['a'].loc[[0, 1]].tolist()` . But this works at column level.

Comment: it’s quite easy to get an array with values: df.loc[[2, 4]] = df.loc[[0, 1]].values